# Get the first x fields in a line using AWK

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a command line utility which generates output like this:

```
Amelia Earhart Dam, Mystic River, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts                               Ref 42.3950∞ N,  71.0767∞ W
Annisquam, Lobster Cove, Massachusetts                                                       Sub 42.6550∞ N,  70.6767∞ W
Barnstable Harbor, Beach Point, Cape Cod Bay, Massachusetts                                  Sub 41.7217∞ N,  70.2850∞ W
Boston Light, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts                                                   Ref 42.3283∞ N,  70.8917∞ W
Boston, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts                                                         Ref 42.3548∞ N,  71.0534∞ W
```

I need to extract the items from the beginning of the line through the state name (Massachusetts can change but I can feed in a variable).

This AWK command gets everything up to the state name:

`awk -F 'Massachusetts' '{print $1}' stations.txt`

How do I configure an AWK command to include the state name but not the rest of the line? I guess I can always post-process add the state name to the fields before it but that seems AWKward, so to speak.

Comment: You should include an input line like `Boston Light, Massachusetts Harbor, Massachusetts                                                   Ref 42.3283∞ N,  70.8917∞ W` or you'll get solutions that fail when the state name appears earlier in the input. Also state names that contain spaces might be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your awk program prints the first `Massachusetts` delimited string (`-F` equals *input field separator* `FS`) but since there is nothing to separate, won't output the separator. And if the separator was outputed, awk would output the *output field separator* `OFS` which is a space by default. Using your approach you could print up to the `FS` and the `FS`:

```
$ awk -F 'Massachusetts' '{print $1 FS}' stations.txt
```

You could also take the state name in as a variable and replace everything from the state name to the end (`$`):

```
$ awk -v state="Massachusetts" '{sub(state".*$",state)} 1' stations.txt
Amelia Earhart Dam, Mystic River, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
Annisquam, Lobster Cove, Massachusetts
Barnstable Harbor, Beach Point, Cape Cod Bay, Massachusetts
Boston Light, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
Boston, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
```

Comment: Perfect, as I was planning to pass in a variable for the various states concerned.

Answer (score 1):

If you think `awk` is an overkill for this task then `grep` can do this.

```
grep -o '^.*Massachusetts' inputfile
Amelia Earhart Dam, Mystic River, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
Annisquam, Lobster Cove, Massachusetts
Barnstable Harbor, Beach Point, Cape Cod Bay, Massachusetts
Boston Light, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
Boston, Boston Harbor, Massachusetts
```

*Above code will start printing from start of the line (`^`)  including any character till `Massachusetts`. If you wish to have multiple field separators then*

```
grep -o '^.*(Massachusetts|NEXT-SEPARATOR|ANOTHER-SEPARATOR|Nth-SEPRATOR)' inputfile
```

Comment: Funny, the grep expression looks right but I can't make it work here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/(Massachusetts).*/\1/' file
```

or, one way of translation to `awk`

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub("(Massachusetts).*","\\1",1)}1' file
```